# Mongoose remove single object from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mail schema:

```
var mail = new mongoose.Schema({
    from: {type: String, required: true},
    subject: {type: String, required: true},
    text: {type: String},
    note: {type: String},
    createdAt: {type: Date, required: true},
    files: [
        {
            fileName: {type: String},
            fileSize: {type: Number},
            fileType: {type: String}
        }
    ]
});
mongoose.model('Mail', mail);
```

I used the following code to remove single file from mail but all files was removed :(

```
  Mail.update({_id: mailId}, {"$pull": {"files": {"fileName": file.fileName}}}).exec(function (err, obj) {
         //do something 
  });
```

I tried a lot of solutions, please can anyone give me a solution for this problem.

Comment: What is your Mongoose version?

Comment: mongoose v5.3.2

Comment: i used the same query, for me it removed a single document from "files" array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry it was a problem in my code